# How were foreign names written in runes?

Tags: vikings, names, writing, norse-mythology

Are there any example of runic writing of a foreign name? Maybe journals or histories from famous  warriors, travelers or foes?

If so, how they do it with the runes?

Basically I'm trying to find how would they write my name

Comment: A number of Celtic (as opposed to Norse) names were recorded in runes on the Isle of Man. There's a paper by Raymond Page on Manx inscriptions in [Runes and Runic Inscriptions](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=solYSR2sUB0C&q=%22celtic+names%22#v=snippet&q=%22celtic%20names%22&f=false)

Comment: This was long before the first dictionaries, so no standardised spellings. "Foreign", as opposed to "Norse" names seem to have been written phonetically.

Comment: I think we've established that runic alphabets were phonetic, so foreign names would have been written the same way as all other words - phonetically (and inconsistently).  How they would have written Xhark depends on how it is pronounced (X and XH are associated with a variety of sounds), and on which runic alphabet (Younger Futhark? Elder Futhark?)  '

Comment: I see.. My name is Elwood, Xhakr is just a name. And I was thibking about younger futhark

Comment: Just take the futhark you like and try to do it. Maybe the only complication would be picking a vowel for the 'oo' digraph. Here is the key reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse#Phonology

Comment: Use the rune converter: http://www.vikingrune.com/rune-converter/ after figuring out what the origin of your name is or how it would have sounded phonetically to one of the old Germanic languages speaking people.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Latin written in runes]
This is one of the medieval rune inscriptions from Bryggen in Bergen, Norway. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryggen_inscriptions. It is in Latin and reads "rexiudeorum innomini patrisnazarenus" - "Rex Judæorum In nomine Patris Nazarenus" - "King of the Jews in the name of the Father of Nazareth".

There are also plenty of foreign names in inscription B013, same wikipedia page.

The answer to the OP's question would seem to be "straight transliteration". "Mark" is easily expressed in all of older, younger or medieval runes.

Comment: Mark edited the original question. Elwood asked it. So we would have to express "Elwood".